# Laravel 5 Namespace Issues

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces, laravel-5

Whilst testing out Laravel 5 I seem to be having some namespace issues. I have tried a few combinations, but this is the one I believe should work (well, according to my understanding). Was hoping I could get some help with it - I would like to understand my mistake, ideally not just a correction of code :)

**UsersController.php**

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\User;
use AllStars\Transformers\UserTransformer;

class UsersController extends Controller {

    protected $userTransformer;

    function __construct(UserTransformer $userTransformer)
    {
        $this->userTransformer = $userTransformer;
    }
```

**Transformer.php**

```
<?php namespace AllStars\Transformers;

abstract class Transformer {

    public function transformCollection(array $items)
    {
        return array_map([$this, 'transform'], $items);
    }

    public abstract function transform($item);
}
```

**UserTransformer.php**

```
<?php namespace AllStars\Transformers;

class UserTransformer extends Transformer {

    private function transform($user)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $user['id'],
            'name' => $user['name'],
            'email' => $user['email'],
        ];
    }
}
```

When I use my UsersController, I get the following error:

> ReflectionException in Container.php line 833: Class
>   AllStars\Transformers\UserTransformer does not exist

Any additional information required, please let me know!

Comment: Try running: `composer update`

Comment: Your namespacing must strictly follow your path in order to work.

Comment: @RobinValk I tried and it's still the same issue.

Comment: See @Ravan's comment

Comment: @RavanMy Transformer files are under app/AllStars/Transformers/ and the controller is under app/Http/Controllers/ is that correct?

Comment: `namespace App\AllStars\Transformers;` try to add  `App` in  the front.

Comment: And @Ravan I see what you mean now! Thanks too!

Comment: @Ravan that's a misconception. there's no hard and fast rule to that.

Comment: @itachi, since he's using Laravel-5, it's taking advantage of Composer's autoloading, which uses  [`psr-4`](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) for `app` folder, that requires it.